# PostgreSQL RLS policy to specific user is not working as expected and applies to all users

Tags: postgresql, policy, row-level-security

I have 2 users in my DB, one is "strong" and one is "weak".
I want to apply RLS policy only for one of them, the weak user.
Meaning, when strong user queries the table, it should get all rows. But when weak user queries the table, the policy will be applied and it will return only allowed rows.

I have created a table, and applied the RLS policy only to the weak user.
But even when querying with the strong user, the policy is executed and prevents me from getting all rows.
I'm using PostgreSQL version 11.4.

Here is how I created the policy (I've created the policy with another 3rd user which is an admin and the owner of the table)

```
CREATE TABLE account_test
(
    id bigserial not null,
    description varchar(200),
    tenant_id UUID not null
);
ALTER TABLE account_test ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
CREATE POLICY tenant_policy ON account_test TO weak_user
                        USING (tenant_id = current_setting('rls.tenant_id')::uuid);
```

```
account=# select * from pg_policies;

 schemaname |  tablename   |  policyname   | permissive |     roles     | cmd |                             qual                             | with_check
------------+--------------+---------------+------------+---------------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 account    | account_test | tenant_policy | PERMISSIVE | **{weak_user}**   | ALL | (tenant_id = (current_setting('rls.tenant_id'::text))::uuid) |
```

Now, inserting and selecting with admin user always works, because it is the owner:

```
insert into account_test (description, tenant_id) VALUES ('desc111', '11111111-c929-462e-ade4-074c81643191');
select * from account_test;
```

no problem here and all rows returned.

When trying to login with weak_user and select, I get no rows as expected:

```
select * from account_test; 
-- returns 0 rows as expected (weak_user).
```

If I set the parameter, policy applies and I get the data as expected:

```
select set_config('rls.tenant_id', '11111111-c929-462e-ade4-074c81643191',true);
select * from account_test; 
-- returns 1 row as expected
```

Now, when I login with strong_user and perform the `select * from account_test` query, I expect all rows to be returned because policy applies only for weak_user.
However, I get the same behavior as for `weak_user` and no rows return.
Also the query with set_config does not return anything.

What am I missing?

Is that the expected behavior?

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4):

The moment you enable RLS on a table with `ALTER TABLE account_test ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY`, a default-deny all policy is used for all users.

> When [RLS] is enabled on a table, all normal access to the table for selecting rows or modifying rows must be allowed by a row security policy. (However, the table's owner is typically not subject to row security policies.) If no policy exists for the table, a default-deny policy is used, meaning that no rows are visible or can be modified.

– https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html

> Each policy has a name and multiple policies can be defined for a table. As policies are table-specific, each policy for a table must have a unique name. Different tables may have policies with the same name.

In order for `strong_user` to have access, you will need to add another rule, e.g.

```sql
CREATE POLICY tenant_policy ON account_test TO strong_user USING (true);
```

> When multiple policies apply to a given query, they are combined using either OR (for permissive policies, which are the default) or using AND (for restrictive policies). This is similar to the rule that a given role has the privileges of all roles that they are a member of. Permissive vs. restrictive policies are discussed further below.

Comment: Thank you @Gajus for the detailed and well explained answer.